# What's wrong with my AM/PM to 24H clock conversion algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I've made an algorithm in C++ for converting AM/PM into 24H clock (ex input 1:10PM/output 13:10). Whenever I enter something it outputs something that I didn't expect(ex 11:11AM outputs 143:11) and after I did something it doesn't even output anymore! I think I broke the logic as I am a beginner.
What have I done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=0;
string x;

cin>>x;

for(i;i<=x.length();i++){
    if(x[x.length()-2]=='A'){
        if(x[0]=='1' && x[1]=='2'){
            x[0]='0';
            x[1]='0';
            x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), 'A'), x.end());
            x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), 'M'), x.end());
        }

        else{
            x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), 'A'), x.end());
            x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), 'M'), x.end());
        }
    }

    else{
        if(x[0]=='1' && x[1] != ':'){
            switch(x[1]){
            case '0':
                x[0]='2';
                x[1]='2';
                break;
            case '1':
                x[0]='2';
                x[1]='3';
                break;
            case '2':
                x[0]='0';
                x[1]='0';
                break;
            }
        }

        else{
            switch(x[0]){
            case '1':
                x.insert(1,"3");
                break;
            case '2':
                x.insert(1,"4");
                break;
            case '3':
                x.insert(1,"5");
                break;
            case '4':
                x.insert(1,"6");
                break;
            case '5':
                x.insert(1,"7");
                break;
            case '6':
                x.insert(1,"8");
                break;
            case '7':
                x.insert(1,"9");
                break;
            case '8':
                x[0]='2';
                x.insert(1,"0");
                break;
            case '9':
                x[0]='2';
                x.insert(1,"1");
                break;
            }
            x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), 'P'), x.end());
            x.erase(remove(x.begin(), x.end(), 'M'), x.end());
        }
    }
}

cout<<x<<endl;






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i;i<=x.length();i++)`. Valid indices are from `0` to `length - 1`. That's your first issue. What happened when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: This seems very complicated. Wouldn't it be easier to parse the user input into `int hour, minute; bool isPM;` ? Or something like that?

Comment: Wait, you never USE `i`. Why are you looping?

Comment: My debugger didn't say anything and I didn't think of that system but my problem, on which I am doing this algorithm, requires only one input

Comment: I used a for a loop because I am used to it and I am not familiar with this kind of problem.I am in 8th grade so I am still learning and from what I saw a for loop is used for this kind of things

Comment: It worked! I removed the for loop and worked perfectly! But the problem-solving app that I was solving the problem had some issues. Thank you again!

Comment: "My debugger didn't say anything" then you're using your debugger wrong. You should set a breakpoint and single step through your program, inspecting all relevant variables after each line. You can see your program changing in real time, and see EXACTLY what line causes your program to diverge from the expected algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that.